# how to compute the adequate distribution and its confidential error for data histogram?

Tags: python, static

I need to extract confidential error for a set of data which is resulted from a set of linear regression parameters( y= ax+b, my data are the parameter a).

I plotted histrogram from my data. I am using python. I got this plot:

I am not good in statistics. I really need advice.I need to check the distributionof my data and extract their confidential error:
- how to analyze my results the time that  curves does not adequate with the histogram sizes? 
- how to check that the distribution is compatible with the normal law or must I use another law?

This is my code that I have used to plot normal distribution curve,

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns

values = [6.460042e-10, 4.173214e-19, 8.806035e-17, 8.826609e-17]
sns.distplot(values)

# find minimum and maximum of xticks, so we know
# where we should compute theoretical distribution
xt = plt.xticks()[0]
xmin, xmax = min(xt), max(xt)
lnspc = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, len(values))

# The normal distribution
m, s = stats.norm.fit(values)  # mean and standard deviation
pdf_g = stats.norm.pdf(lnspc, m, s)  # now get theoretical values in our interval
print('theoretical values in our interval'+str(pdf_g))
plt.plot(lnspc, pdf_g, label="Norm")  # plot it

# exactly same as above
ag,bg,cg = stats.gamma.fit(values)
pdf_gamma = stats.gamma.pdf(lnspc, ag, bg,cg)
plt.plot(lnspc, pdf_gamma, label="Gamma")

ab,bb,cb,db = stats.beta.fit(values)
pdf_beta = stats.beta.pdf(lnspc, ab, bb,cb, db)
plt.plot(lnspc, pdf_beta, label="Beta")

plt.show()
```

[image]
I would be very grateful if you could conduct me please.

Comment: What specific normal distribution do you want to compare to? What you have shown is not a histogram, did you mean to show one? Can you show us the code you used to try to plot this with the curve of a normal distribution yourself? I suspect this forum is not the appropriate venue for your question.

Comment: @JordanSinger I have edited my question. I put my code. The problem for me is how to analyze my results. How to decide that this curve is applied to a normal law.